# CSS Hover entire row as well as single cell

Tags: html, css

How do I add a hover style to highlight a row that the cursor is on as well as another hover class to highlight the one specific cell(diff color, etc) that the cursor is on?

HTML

```
<table>
 <tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
    tr:hover td {bg-color:; color:;} /** Highlights row**/
```

Comment: td: hover {} highlights the one cell but does not work at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Use instead

```
tr td:hover {bg-color:; color:;} /** Highlights row**/
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need something similar to this.

```
tr:hover {background-color:#000; color:#ff0000;} <!-- row hover
tr td:hover {background-color:#CCC; color:#fff;}  <!-- individual cell hover
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to color the specific row than one of the way is to give it class name and change the color when hover over that class

HTML

```
<table border=1>
  <tr class="first">
     <td> some value</td>
     <td>some value </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="second">
     <td>some value </td>
     <td>some value </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="second">
     <td>some value </td>
     <td>some value </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.first:hover {
   color: red; 
 }
```

try running this code. Here when you hover over first row it will change the color of first row.